# C++ Pass stdcall function name as parameter

Tags: c++, c

I am unable to pass stdcall function name "TestFunction" as parameter into ExecuteLocalThread and to use in beginthreadex

```
unsigned __stdcall TestFunction(void* timerPointer)
{
    unsigned result =0;
    printf("thread is running\n");
    return result;
}

void ExecuteLocalThread(unsigned int (_stdcall *_StartAddress)(void *))
{
    HANDLE   heartBeatThread;
    unsigned int hbThreadID;
    heartBeatThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0 , unsigned int (_stdcall *_StartAddress)(void *)/*&TestFunction*/, (void*)this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &hbThreadID);
    ResumeThread( heartBeatThread );
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?  Did you try using just `_StartAddress` in your call to `_beginthreadex`?

Comment: Agree. Remove the casts. They just turn a compile-time error into a runtime error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
heartBeatThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0 , _StartAddress/*&TestFunction*/, (void*)this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &hbThreadID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest making a typedef for the function pointer, and using this everywhere else:

```
typedef unsigned int _stdcall (*Pfn)(void*); // typedefs to "Pfn"

void ExecuteLocalThread(Pfn _StartAddress)
{
    HANDLE   heartBeatThread;
    unsigned int hbThreadID;
    heartBeatThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, _StartAddress, (void*)this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &hbThreadID);
    ResumeThread( heartBeatThread );
}
```

It's easier to type, easier to read and harder to mess up ;) Even casting gets easier with it: To cast `somePtr` to your function pointer type: `(Pfn)somePtr`

Comment: I appreciate your quick help, StackHeapCollision and lethal-guitar. this is really helpful (solved). thank you :)